# OR Operator in WHERE Clause takes more time for Execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

While adding **OR** operator in **WHERE Clause** it takes more time for execution to complete.

I am using two tables in my Stored Procedure.

I need to check two conditions in my query and which is also very simple.

But unfortunately we are unable to create **Index** for these table columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.ID=TBL2.ID
WHERE (@Code = TBL1.Code OR @Code IS NULL)
AND (@Port = TBL1.POL OR @Port = TBL1.POD OR @Port IS NULL)
```

Even though, I checked twice without these conditions it takes 0.35 sec with 9k rows

But when it add these conditions in `where` clause it takes more than 2 min.

Note: Sorry I'm unable to provide sample data for this issue.

Comment: can you describe the table schemas?

Comment: I have to return all the matching rows from both the tables when passing **@Code**  and **@Port** as NULL @DmitryKolchev

Comment: @Thiyagu btw sample data does not need to contain sensitive information, it just needs to reproduce the issue i.e. a [mre]. When providing such a limited amount of information there isn't going to be much help we can give.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) and [Revisiting catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this, using CASE:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.ID=TBL2.ID
WHERE 1 = (CASE WHEN @Code IS NULL THEN 1 
                WHEN @Code = TBL1.Code THEN 1 END)
AND 1 = (CASE WHEN @Port IS NULL THEN 1 
              WHEN @Port = TBL1.POL THEN 1 
              WHEN @Port = TBL1.POD THEN 1 END)
```

I've sometimes experienced using "OR" to be the slowest alternative. YMMV.
You could also try query hints.

Comment: I'd be very interested to see if that works - its a great alternative.

Comment: Yeah bro I already tried this. This Improves performance also. But my management negotiates this logic by saying that it looks like a terrible code.

What actually I'm actually need that to avoid hard coding 1 on both the LHS and RHS

@MoeSisko

Comment: @Thiyagu - this technique checks that the left hand side is equal to the right hand side, so there has to be some value on the left that the right can compare with. 1 is what I usually use for this sort of thing, but it could be anything. e.g. 0, "TRUE". But changing that constant probably won't help to make this code "look" any better.

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding the following index to the first table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON TBL1 (Code, POL, POD, ID);
```

Assuming SQL Server would use the above index, it would execute the query by scanning `TBL2` but using the index for the join and where restrictions.  You may also try this version of the index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON TBL1 (ID, Code, POL, POD);
```

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to create an Index for those Columns. Can we have any other solution to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, adding an index is the only thing which comes to mind.

Comment: Is there any other possibilities to try?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have no option to add indexes you can sometimes improve `OR` performance by converting your query to use `UNION ALL` - which if I have got it right gives the following 6 components to cover all permutations.

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
WHERE @Code = TBL1.Code AND @Port = TBL1.POL

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
WHERE @Code = TBL1.Code AND @Port = TBL1.POD

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
WHERE @Code = TBL1.Code AND @Port IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
WHERE @Code IS NULL AND @Port = TBL1.POL

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
WHERE @Code IS NULL AND @Port = TBL1.POD

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
WHERE @Code IS NULL AND @Port IS NULL;
```

Comment: Is there no option to handle this in Where Clause?

Comment: @Thiyagu the option to handle it in the where clause is called `OR` - you've already tried that.

Comment: @DmitryKolchev yeah, with 6 branches its probably not a great solution. Seems like general performance tuning is required regardless of the query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM TBL1 INNER JOIN
     TBL2
     ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
WHERE [where]
;

declare @where nvarchar(max)';

set @where = @where + (case when @code is not null then N'tbl1.code = @code and' else '' end);
set @where = @where + (case when @port is  not null then N'@port in (tbl1.pol, tbl1.pod) and'

set @sql = @sql + @where + N' 1=1';

exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@code <type here>; @port <type here>',
                   @code=@code, @port=@port;
```

This generates only the code that is needed, so it will be optimized correctly.

The overhead of recompiling the query should be minimal compared to the time used for running the query (unless the two tables are trivially small).